# How to add real-time listener to firebase query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've created a database to store my logs and get real-time update of my log entries for the last 1 hour

I've tried adding a real-time listener to my firebase query. Both attempt triggered once (upon start-up), but didn't trigger when a new log was added while the app is already running

Here are my code

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("logs");

long MillisInHour = 60*60*1000;//one hour
```

Here is the query

```
Query query = myRef.orderByChild("timeStamp").startAt(System.currentTimeMillis()).endAt(System.currentTimeMillis() - MillisInHour);
```

I've tried (Attempt #1)

```
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Also (Attempt #2)

```
query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I should have used

```
Query query = myRef.orderByChild("timeStamp").startAt(System.currentTimeMillis() - MillisInHour)
```

instead.